# Реализация кода Грея

Tags: java

Ребята, помогите с кодом грея. Не могу довести до ума. В ответ выводит 1110, 1110, 1111, 1111.

```
import java.io.*;

public class cod {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int m;
    String settext = "";

    int i = 4; //указываем длинну
    double k = Math.pow(2, i);
    int[][] code = new int[int k][i + 1];
    code[1][i] = 0;
    code[2][i] = 1;
    for (int a = 2; a <= i; a++) {
        m = (int) (Math.pow(2, a));
        for (int b = (int) (Math.pow(2, a - 1)) + 1; b <= m; b++) {
            code[b] = code[m - b + 1];
            code[m - b + 1][i - a + 1] = 0;
            code[b][i + 1 - a] = 1;
        }
    }
    for (int n = 1; n <= k; n++) {
        for (int q = 1; q <= i; q++) {
            settext = Integer.toString(code [n][q]) ;
            System.out.print(settext);

            System.out.print (" ");

        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: больше информации, что вы хотите получить?

Comment: @Viacheslav, ты что код грея не знаешь?)))))

Comment: надо чтоб выводил 0000  0001  0010 и т.д.
а получается 1110  1110  1111 1111 и т.д.

Comment: я знаю его, но не знаю как написать, чтоб работало нужным языком

Comment: учусь на программиста первый год

Comment: мне не надо преобразовывать просто надо чтоб вывел такую последовательность, но не используя готовый массив, я понятно излагаю?

Comment: в вашем коде чёрт ногу сломит, и комментарии вида `//указываем длинну` ничем не помогают, если бы вы называния переменных хоть как-то соответсвовали их назначению и комментарии были "не для галочки", может всё было намного проще, вас этому не учат?

Comment: @Gorets, знаю, просто данный кусок кода, как написали выше - непонятен.

Answer (score 3):

Прочитайте статью на [Вики](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%8F) там конкретные примеры на C. Останется только сделать порт на Java. Причем там код значительно оптимальнее Вашего.
**UPD**
Приведенный в [статье](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/GrayCode.java.html) код делает именно то, что Вы хотите на Java.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at cod.main(cod.java:23)
вот эту

Comment: ну нынче такое обучение, что делай все сам  как ты это сделаешь мало кого "имеет"

Comment: System.out.println("0000");
System.out.println("0001");
System.out.println("0010"); да вывел именно это но не используя задание массива таким образом и соответственно нельзя через принтлн

Comment: Я тестировал у себя, прежде чем запостить :) Все работает.  

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        gray("", N);
    }
Надо просто либо аргументы передавать, либо

    int N=4;

Answer (score 1):

Вот довольно [лаконичная реализация](http://olympbrain.com/theory/ext_theory.aspx?ext_page=MiuHE7eIe9vPHSifYhEBSrW4VyTcOccK0wWdXu+KJLT8gUFPTEShdA==):

```
int g (int n) {
return n ^ (n >> 1);
}
```

Этот метод находит следующей, зная предыдущий.

Comment: на wiki тоже этот пример есть

Comment: Только это С. На Java эта конструкция дает не то, что нужно.